# How to disable links in React when rendering content using dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a website using React and users can type or copy text for example from Wikipedia into an input.

The main problem was that the copied text is rendered as html so I fixed that problem using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and securing it with `DOMPurify` like this

```
<Typography variant="body"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
         __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(item.label)
      }}
/>
```

The problem is that I don't want links and redirection from that typed text later when rendering it.

How can I fix this please?

Comment: Could you add an example of the ``item.label`` value ?

Answer (score 1):

If I assume that your `item.label` value is something like :

```
<div>
  Hello world
  <a href="wikipedia.com">Here is the explanation</a>
</div>
```

The only way I could think of is to use [the replace function](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Something like that :

```js
let str = "<div>Hello world<a href='wikipedia.com'>Here is the explanation</a></div>";
const result = str.replace(/(href=["'])([A-Za-z-\\\/:.]*)(["'])/ig, "");
console.log(result);

// You could also just replace the website with '#' in order to keep the link effect but to stay in the same page :
const result2 = str.replace(/(href=["'])([A-Za-z-\\\/:.]*)(["'])/ig, "$1#$3");
console.log(result2);

// Or even delete the link itself :
const temp = str.replace(/(<a[ ]*href=["'])([A-Za-z-\\\/:.]*)(["']>)/ig, " ");
const result3 = temp.replace(/<\/a>/ig, "");
console.log(result3);
```

Comment: You are right, but I wanted something more easier and it turned out `dompurify` has something like this `FORBID_ATTR` . Thank you.